# Rally - Create User Story with tags using REST (non-API)

Tags: rest, tags, rally

How do I add/attach tags while creating/updating user stories in Rally? I'm using the below JSON script and I'm getting a error "cannot find referenced object".  What am I missing?

```
{
"HierarchicalRequirement": {
    "Description": "As a developer to create a user story",
    "Name": "User story to be created",
    "Notes": "Created via REST Client",
    "Project": {
        "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/1302421049",
        "_refObjectName": "Sample Project",
        "_type": "Project"
    },
    "Tags": {
        "_type": "Tag",
        "_tagsNameArray": [{
            "Name": "My Tag"
        }],
        "Count": 1
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Leo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to encode your tags a little differently and you'll have it.  Tags (and all collections) expect to be specified as an array of objects with _ref properties like so:

```
"Tags": [
    {
        "_ref": "/tag/12345"
    },
    {
        "_ref": "/tag/23456"
    }
]
```